# PHP resources type list - such as copy(RESOURCE, ...)

Tags: php, stream, resources

I am trying to gain understanding of capabilities and limitations of paths as specified in functions like copy(a, b).  Until recently I thought only traditional file paths (/path/to/file.obj) could be used as parameters here. But i found in a ZipArchive comment, a mention of syntax like:

```
copy('zip:///path/to/zip#file/to/extract', ...)
```

... and realized there may be a vast area of capability I'm missing.  I've tried various searches of the manual to help me understand what other capabilities may be available in 'path' (surely http:// for one) but none of my searches (php paths, php resources, php stream specification, etc.) have led to any insight...

Can someone point me to an article that goes in depth on these specs and their limitations and capabilities, please?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Start here [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php). I don't see `zip:`, maybe it's added in an extension.

Comment: BTW, I got that link from the documentation of `copy()`.

Comment: @Barmar Ugh, I completely overlooked stream_context_create(), which does lead eventuality to there. My mistake.   If you make your comment an Answer, I will accept it.  Thanks so much. So quick, so good.

Comment: By the way, the comment I referenced may be found in the first Note, here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the main [Filesystem Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) documentation, you'll find the link to [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) page, which lists the protocols that can be used in pathnames. `zip://` isn't listed there, but it's possible to add additional wrappers in PHP using [`stream_wrapper_register()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php) and with extensions.

Comment: Thanks, @barmar, for the immediate and correct answer!  Yes, since ZipArchive is an extension, it makes sense that the registration facility made that additional function possible.  Sort of a shame that there doesn't seem to be a more exhaustive list including common extensions, but this will get me what I was looking for.  At present, ssh2:// looks like just the thing I hoped to find!  Double goodness!